# Deleting row in java Derby database

Tags: java, derby

I am on the last page of this tutorial: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/delete_a_record_from_a_database.html which is about deleting a record in a Derby database. My code for the delete-button is as follows:

```java
private void btnDeleteRecordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
   try{

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String uName = "bjorn";
    String uPass= "";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  App.Workers",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    //count++;
     if (rs.absolute(count)) {
    rs.absolute(count);
    //rs.next();
    rs.deleteRow( );

    pstmt.close( );
    rs.close( );
     }

   }
   catch (SQLException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
   }

}
```

I have two questions:
Why does `rs.deleteRow( );` not work?
When I include the following code in the method, it gives me the error:

```
Invalid operation at current cursor position.

stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM App.Workers";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first2 = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last2 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job2 = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first2);
        textLastName.setText(last2);
        textJobTitle.setText(job2);
        stmt.close( );
```

This code is supposed to reload all the data in the Text Fields. What is the working code that doesn't give this exception?

Answer (score 1):

1. ResultSet.deleteRow() deletes row from the `ResultSet` and DB, but you have to call the `ResultSet.next()` to get to the 1st row before you can delete or read something. Also, `deleteRow()` deletes the current row, and as you don't have a current row set, there is nothing to delete.
2. Before you can use `ResultSet` to get items, you first have to do a `ResultSet.next()`, to get to the first row.

For your problem, add the line `rs.next();` after you do `executeQuery()`, in both the cases. But please note, this is just a quick fix, you should always check whether there are rows available, and perform your task.

Comment: My application crashes when I press the Delete-button, whatever I try. Can you provide me the working code by changing the code above?